# VMware guest ip same group of host

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I am using VMware 12 in Ubuntu 16.04 to run a Windows guest.

My Linux eth0 configuration is:

```
ip 143.106.14.237
netmask 25 (255.255.255.128)
gtway 143.106.14.129
DNS 8.8.8.8
```

I want to put my Windows guest in the same IP group of my host, to it be also visible to the local network equipment. I know that I have to modify the `/etc/vmware/vmnet1/dhcpd/dhcp.conf` or `/etc/vmware/vmnet8/dhcpd/dhcp.conf` files.

But, which is the better configuration to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the bridge configuration and set the IP in the guest OS.